# Should I snowflake (which I do not want to, but THINK I need to) or should I create a second dimension with a lot of reduntant information?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

In the RDMS the model looks like this:

```
---------------------               ---------------------
| ContractTable     |               | CoverageTable     |
---------------------               ---------------------
| ContractID        |   --1:M ------| CoverageID        |
| CoverageID        |--/            | Coverage info...  |
| Contract info...  |               ---------------------
---------------------
```

I am making 2 dimensions. dimContract and dimContractCoverage. Should dimContractCoverage have all of the same descriptive columns in it as dimContracts + the info relevant to a coverage OR should I just snowflake? Snowflake is the easy answer, but I am looking for some reassurance.

Comment: What is your fact?

Comment: Snowflaking is rarely the right answer, but we can't tell you for sure without understanding more of your model. As Ron has asked, information about your fact would be helpful. As it stands I'm not sure why you feel you'd need to repeat data, either - some clarification on your thinking there might help.

Comment: This is the beginning of our DW so I am wanting to create conformed dimensions which should apply to multiple facts. For this example, the fact is an accumulating monthly snapshot of how many $ have been claimed against, accrued, or is in reserve for each contract. I could get by with a single Contract dimension and summarize the coverage data in it (i think).

As to why I think we will need to repeat data:only in the scenario with 2 dimensions would this apply, but if I make a coverage dimension down the road there is so much contract info needed in the coverage dim I would